# Drawing multi polyline using Google Maps SDK there is cut on every joint of polyline

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-polyline

When I add multiple polylines using Google Maps SDK 8.1.0 in iOS, the joints of every polyline I see are cut. I want a smooth polyline at each joint as well either overlap. Here is the code and screenshot attached. Though I am using sprite image, I even tried using solid color and the same issue is happening. Also attaching image.

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()

for coordinate in stepInfo.stepLatLng {
    path.add(coordinate)
}

let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeWidth = 14
polyline.strokeColor = .blue
let image = UIImage(named: "nav_path", in: Bundle.mapsSdk, compatibleWith: nil)!

let redWithStamp = GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.red)
redWithStamp.stampStyle = GMSTextureStyle(image: image)
let span = GMSStyleSpan(style: redWithStamp)
   
polyline.spans = [span]
polyline.geodesic = true
  
polyline.map = mapView
```

[image]

Comment: Maps SDK for Android have this `jointType` option for `PolylineOptions`, but I can't see it in the Maps SDK for iOS. I think filing a feature request for it to be available also in iOS would be good. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Comment: I got solution rather than rendering each different polyline to method to draw polyline on foreach, what i did collected all points into array  and then passed whole array to create all polylines in one go and that solved this issue.

Comment: Oh I just realized that you were doing that. hahaha I was wondering why your polyline looked like this.